# How to erase or clear UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How can I make a text field box remove all content on the user's first keypress?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if([tfieldDOB.text length] == 4)
    {
        tfieldDOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",tfieldDOB.text];
    }
    else if([tfieldDOB.text length]==7)
    {
        tfieldDOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",tfieldDOB.text];
        
    }
    
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: after typing we can't clear it.@pe60t0

Answer (score 12):

change the textfield attribute clear button mode in `appears while editing`

[image]

or other choice  just use the single line, where you need to add

```
yourtextfieldname.text=@"";  //it is used for clear the textfield values
```

**Swift**

```
yourtextfieldname.text=""
```

or another way

```
 clearField =@"YES";

if([clearField isequaltostring:@"YES"])  //check this line in 
{
    tfieldDOB.text = @"";
    clearField =@"NO";
}
```

Comment: suppose i type 1990/11/11,and when i want to edit it then only last two digit edited  ..i.e not completely edit..@anbu

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    
    
    
    if([tfieldDOB.text length] == 4)
    {
        tfieldDOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",tfieldDOB.text];
    }
    else if([tfieldDOB.text length]==7)
    {
        tfieldDOB.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",tfieldDOB.text];
        
    }

    return YES;
    
}

Comment: k where is your clearfield condition, where declare the clearfield value,

Comment: first of all tfieldDOB is empty,now i've typed my date of birth 1990/11/01,but suppose i want to edit it then i can edit only (1990/11/)..@anbu

Answer (score 5):

Implement the text field's delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` and set the text as empty string when the text field is just about to being editing.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField setText:@""];
    return YES;
}
```

Or you can set the property `clearsOnBeginEditing` of the textfield as

```
[textField setClearsOnBeginEditing:YES];
```

and it will clear the text when editing begins